# I am trying to make a ocr. how will the computer read the plain text in jpeg file ?

Tags: ocr

I am a starter & trying to make a ocr. how will the computer read the plain text in jpeg file ?

Comment: How To Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: About OCR: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188104/character-recognition-ocr-algorithm